# jQuery In Custom Login Screen xhtml

Tags: javascript, jquery, cognos, cognos-bi

I need to use jquery in a custom login form that I am creating but i cant find a way to do it.

I have tried including the script tag but nothing happens:

```
<script src="/cognos/ps/login/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
```

I can successfully include custom css in the login xhtml page but javascript of any kind.

Standard javascript works though. Adding something like:

```
<script>
      alert("I am here!");
</script>
```

works. I am adding the necessary noConflict() statement and everything that various posts suggest but no luck. Note that all relative posts i have found explain how to use jQuery in a cognos report html, not in login screen.

Comment: Did you try to use jQuery and not $?
var j = jQuery.noConflict();
Like suggested here (I know it is related to report, but still worth a try):
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ba-pp-reporting-advanced-report-design-page647/

Comment: thanks! Yes i have tried all the possibilities that many docs give but they seem to work only in reports. Login screen is being rendered in a specific way...cognos.cgi does its magic

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("script")).setAttribute("src","http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js")
</script>
```

Comment: Nope! it does it include it..I think cognos.cgi doesnt do the job...When i put the noConflict i get jQuery not defined error..Normal since its not included

Comment: execute your jquery code in setTimeout or put the above script in head tag and all other script at the end of page i.e. just before closing body tag

Comment: nope didnt work. Its just whoever builds the login page html doesnt include jquery...I know that he reads the file because in jquery 2.x i get a warning in console and in 1.10 i don't...i also tried to include it in customize() function

Answer (score 0):

I ran a test where I included the script tag towards the end of the file, similar to example one in this document:
http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/cognos/security/cognos_bi_platform/page546.html

Here's the example code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ibmcognos/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        console.log("JQuery is ready");
    });
</script>
```

This works for me.